# Ask Prolog for predicates of an argument

Tags: prolog

Say, we have some facts like

```
musician(sokrates).
philosopher(sokrates).
two_legged(sokrates).
dead(sokrates).
```

Is there any way to ask Prolog for predicates that are valid for 'sokrates' like:

```
X(sokrates).
```

I looked for some syntax to do that, but I can't imagine a solution.

Comment: @TomasBy: How would that be used to solve this problem?  Doesn't =.. require the predicate to be specified on at least one side?

Comment: @mimimi: What do you need this to accomplish?  Maybe there is another way to accomplish it.